# Probability set-theory expansion, dont understand a step.

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I'm currently studying probability and I can't solve a particular exercise. In the solutions manual it states the following step:

$$
P(A ∩ (B ∪ C)^c ) = P(A ∪ B ∪ C) − P(B ∪ C)
$$

I know that to get to this from the previous form $$ P(A ∩ B^c ∩ C^c) $$ a DeMorgan's Law was applied to get to $$ P(A ∩ (B ∪ C)^c ) $$, but how does one arrive at P(A ∪ B ∪ C) − P(B ∪ C)? Which (identity)formula is used here? I can't find/understand why this step is possible.

Please give me some pointer to help me understand.

Comment: It might be better to think of $A\cap(B \cup C)^c$ and $B\cup C$ as disjoint sets, so that $P(A\cap(B \cup C)^c) + P(B\cup C)$ can be seen to be the probability of the union of the two (disjoint) sets.

Comment: $x \in A \cap B^c \cap C^c \iff x \in A \text{ and } x \not \in B\cup C$; while $B\cup C $ is a subset of $A \cup B\cup C $

Comment: Thanks guys! I realise now that I have been hoping too much for a ready to be used formula instead of noticing that $ A∩(B∪C)^c $ and $ B∪C $ are disjoint. Thanks for shining some light on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hardmath has already hinted,$ A∩(B∪C)^c$ and $B∪C$ are disjoint sets, 
so ,$$ P((A∩(B∪C)^c)∪(B∪C)) = P(A∩(B∪C)^c) + P(B∪C)$$ by addition rule

But $$(A∩(B∪C)^c)∪(B∪C) = A∪B∪C$$ 
Therefore,$$P(A∪B∪C) = P(A∩(B∪C)^c) + P(B∪C) $$ which is the desired result.